# how to hide radio button's text in android layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

how to remove text label of radio button to make center and square as in image. i have used this in recycler view it's automatically showing label how  to hide the same.

[image]

### code

```xml
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

### output

[image]

### item in recycler view

[image]

Comment: yes @snachmsm it's same what i'm looking for, thank you